# App rejected due to background location mode

Tags: ios, background, core-location

I including the UIBackgroundModes key (with the location value) in its Info.plist file. If not include the UIBackgroundModes,app can location when run in background? My app not need real-time location update on background.So my app is rejected. App store reply:"We noticed your app declares support for location in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist but does not include features that require persistent location. " My app need location by specific case while app in background.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has rejected your app because it uses too much battery power.

You need to either rewrite your app so that it doesn't use as much battery power or else convince Apple that you need to do it the way you're doing it.

They will allow an app to have heavy battery drain, but only when there is no other way to implement things. Since your app was rejected, there probably is another option.

You could perhaps file a TSI with Apple. https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/submit/